# what's problem a cloudflare cache for Nginx origin server?

Tags: cloudflare

I am using two origin server for Apache and Nginx with Cloudflare CDN.
But caching does not work on Cloudflare for Nginx only.

> Everytime no "HIT"
> Everytime "DYNAMIC"
> "Page Rules" setup for "Everything"

what is the difference between Apache and Nginx when using Cloudflare CDN?

- Note: In Apache, it works very well.

Comment: The "Cache everything" page rule should cache regardless of content type and header and should be returning "HIT" or "MISS" for the CF-Cache-Status header. Can you post an example page rule that should match your nginx server's URL and an example URL that is returning "DYNAMIC" for CF-Cache-Status?

Comment: Yes, It is test cache URL: https://web.kh-poker.com:2053/apk/

Comment: Page Rule setup: web.kh-poker:2053/apk/* for "Cache Level" of "Everything"

Comment: `web.kh-poker:2053/apk/*` wouldn't match `web.kh-poker.com:2053/apk`, you would need a rule that is `web.kh-poker.com:2053/apk*`. However your current rule would match something like `web.kh-poker.com:2053/apk/path` or `web.kh-poker.com:2053/apk/asset.ext`

Comment: Thank you for Help me. I revised it according to your advice. But i have same problem for NO "HIT" everytime "DYNAMIC".

* its works for Cache "HIT" Apache only

Comment: And I have a question.

Cache data "HIT" operates normally without setting "Apache" Page Rule.

But "Nginx" only works with Cache data "DYNAMIC" when you set the Page Rule.

I wonder if it's because of the difference between Apache and Nginx servers, or if CloudFlare has to setup.

Comment: Without a page rule, this should not be the case.  When operating without a page rule Cloudflare should only cache extensions that match static content types like css/js/jpg/png/gif/ico and for everything else you should be seeing DYNAMIC.

Comment: But, it is not working the Cache data thru origin nginx(1.16.1-1 ver.)

Comment: I don't know why this is not working. There should be nothing special about nginx that makes its responses uncacheable.